# visitNumber for successive sessions

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm a bit surprised, how come successive sessions from user have visitNumber == 1 (it happens with more than one users). Doesn't visitNumber (session number for user) increments with each successive session?

see attach screenshot pls.

====

```
SELECT fullvisitorid, visitid, date, visitNumber, hitNumber, type, page.pagePath, isInteraction
FROM `122623284.ga_sessions_2017*` ga_sessions, unnest(hits) as ht
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '0101' and '0731'
      AND fullvisitorid in ('3635735417215222540', '4036640811518552822', '800892955541145796')
ORDER BY fullvisitorid, visitid, hitnumber
```

Thanks in advance, if anyone any idea under what scenarios this can happen ?

cheers!

[image]

UPDATE (after @WillianFuks response)

It's still the same, after re-running the query that @WillianFuks suggested, 
[image]

Comment: You're taking a cross product with `hits`. Does every duplicate visitor ID appear in the same hit? You could use UNNEST(...) WITH OFFSET and include offset in the select list.

Comment: Thanks Elliott! I did use UNNEST in the query..

Comment: Thx for the tip @ElliottBrossard (sorry comments don't allow to upload screenshots, so updated my answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observation here is the stark date difference between the successive visits :

- 188 days (red)
- 210 days (green)
- 184 days (blue)

Analytics does a lookback for the last session to increment the visitNumber count, but there is a limit on number of days it lookbacks upto, called as lookback window. I don't remember exactly for analytics but the lookback window generally ranges from 90 days to 180 days for various Google products. 
Since it is not able to find the previous visit within the lookback window, it resets the visitNumber to 1 again.

Update: By default it is 6 months for Google Analytics.

Comment: Good catch! Just now I noticed it

Comment: thanks @Netham, brilliant catch !! this clarifies a lot, although makes no sense (atleast not to me!) Even if it's related with campaign session reset (?!) the visitNumber resetting to '1' makes no sense..  I wanted to fetch very first visit of a user, seems like i've to play around with min(date) / visitId combination now or perhaps min(visitid) :(  (do you mind sharing more info on this, if its documented somewhere? so that I know more details about it!)

Answer (score 0):

As Elliott suggested in his comment, the problem most likely is due the duplication that happens when you apply `UNNEST` to the *hits* field.

You can confirm that by running this query:

```
SELECT 
  fullvisitorid fv,
  visitid,
  date,
  visitNumber,
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT hitNumber, type, page.pagePath AS pagePath, isInteraction FROM UNNEST(hits)) data
FROM `122623284.ga_sessions_2017*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '0101' and '0731'
  AND fullvisitorid in ('3635735417215222540', '4036640811518552822', '800892955541145796')
LIMIT 1000
```

This will bring the fields inside *hits* without making the cross product (unnest operation) with the outer fields.